# Define rails association only if model does not have children in other association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I am confused how to define association scope on Rails model that will be dependent on other association relationship.

Example:

```
class Company
  has_many :workers 
  has_many :employees
end
```

How can I allow adding workers to company ONLY IF company DOES NOT have any employees? If it has at least one employee, adding workers to company should be rejected and there shouldn't be any workers association displayed in JSON reponse when I retrieve company with at least one employee that belongs to that company.

Any ideas? Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a block to extend your association:

```
  has_many :workers do
    def << (value)
      super value unless ...
    end     
  end
```

More info here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#461-User-a-block-to-extend-your-associations

And to display or not when you serialize the object, you can use the to_json method options like:

```
@company.to_json(only: [:workers])
```

Hope it helps.